# Firebase won't work

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

i don't know if someone have the same problem at the moment, but i'm trying to import Firebase in my app but it only shows "No such module for Firebase". Could anyone please help me?
[This is the error i get every time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AJxq.png)

EDIT: (Sorry for the noobie errors), this is the code in the Podfile:

```
target 'CosplaCentral' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for CosplaCentral

  target 'CosplaCentralTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'CosplaCentralUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
      pod 'Firebase'
    end

end
```

Comment: provide some code (such as your pod file)

Comment: edit your post and provide the code in your Pod File

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the post

Comment: left an answer for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your pod file with the code below, then in `Terminal` direct to your project file and do `pod install` (make sure Xcode is closed when doing so) and then load up your project again then retype `import Firebase`

```
 platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'CosplaCentral' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for LT Sounds
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'

end
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Konsy, you saved me!

Comment: No worries :) glad i could help